# Accessing the Delete key in Google Chrome via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I use the following code to delete a character when the user presses the delete code.
It works in Firefox but doesn't work in Google Chrome.
What do I have to fix?

```
  window.onkeypress = function(key) {
        ...
        if (Guessing>0){
            else if (key.keyCode == 8){//Delete key
                PhraseEntry=PhraseEntry.substring(0, PhraseEntry.length - (1+back))
                    + PhraseEntry.substring(PhraseEntry.length - back, PhraseEntry.length );
                $("display_text").empty( ).append(PhraseEntry);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: It should be noted that it appears to be either a bug or intentionally coded to prevent the detection of the user pressing the delete key in certain circumstances as it IS possible to detect other keys being pressed other then delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`keydown` event](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html) instead (`Delete` is [`keyCode` 46](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/What-is-the-list-of-KeyCodes-for-JavaScript-KeyDown-KeyPress-and-KeyUp-events.aspx)):

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 46) { // Delete key
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onkeypress = function(key)
        {
            alert(key.keyCode);
        }
</script>
```

I'd start with this - put that in your page and hit Delete when viewing it in Chrome :)

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `keydown` event instead.